# How to convert string to datetime in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

I want to convert this string "`Fri, 03 Jun 2016 08:01:26 GMT`" to `datetime` in python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should it work with time zones?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse),

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse("Fri, 03 Jun 2016 08:01:26 GMT")
```

Or use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior),

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime("Fri, 03 Jun 2016 08:01:26 GMT", '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

Comment: Ah cool, didn't know about this one.

Comment: @sparkandshine thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime), the "opposite" of [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime):

```
from time import strptime
strptime('Fri, 03 Jun 2016 08:01:26 GMT', "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

For example:

```
In [26]: strptime('Fri, 03 Jun 2016 08:01:26 GMT', "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
Out[26]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=3, tm_hour=8, tm_min=1, tm_sec=26, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=155, tm_isdst=0)
```